# Wordpress pagination link only works for first page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

This is on my main page, in which I want to display N of the latest posts, and have paginated links at the bottom to view the next N posts.

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <!-- then the pagination links -->
    <?php previous_posts_link('&larr; Previous'); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Next  &rarr;', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
```

The home page works fine, displays the first 2 posts : `http://localhost:8000/`

The first time I click the Next link, it also works fine, and displays the following 2 posts: `http://localhost:8000/?paged=2`

However if I click it again, I get a "Not found" "looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?" screen, even though the URL appears correct (`http://localhost:8000/?paged=3`)

Any idea why that could be happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A weird quirk I found here is that the `posts_per_page` parameter indicates how many are displayed, but the actual counting for the pagination is set in the admin panel, in Settings -> Readings, then in `Blog pages show at most` value.

You can actually remove the `posts_per_page` param and just keep the setting in the Admin panel.